# How to show all list items again that were previously hidden by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box that filters results and hides them if they don't match the filter:

```
$('#box_street').keyup(function() {
                  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                  if (valThis == "") {
                    $('#street__list > .list__item').show();
                  } else {
                    $('#street__list > .list__item').each(function() {
                      var text = ($(this).text() + $(this).data("alt")).toLowerCase();
                      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
                        $(this).show()
                      } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                      }
                    });
                  };
                });
```

Now, I added a function that clear the search box with `$('.search__filter').val('');` The problem is, once that runs the items that were previously hidden don't show again. The form input resets ok, but the items are still hidden.

How can I show them all again?

Comment: Have you tried with trim() on top of toLowerCase() for fixing whitespace problems? Also try debugging to see which values are present when doing the if comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the search input is empty, all you have to do is trigger the `keyup` event, as you already have a condition that shows all the elements

```
$('#reset_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.search__filter').val('');
    // reset form ... then
    $('#box_street').trigger('keyup');
    // or you could do it yourself directly with : 
    // $('#street__list > .list__item').show();
});
```